# Are my charging equations being used correctly in my lithium ion battery Python simulation?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, python

This is a continuation of a previous question I asked ([Are my equations correct for a simple lithium ion battery model in Python?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495348/are-my-equations-correct-for-a-simple-lithium-ion-battery-model-in-python)). My issue now is I do not believe I am using the charge equations correctly for what I am trying to do. I am trying to recreate a plot similar to the plot below.

[image]

Right now I am trying to simulate a simple lithium ion battery that gets randomly charged (`pv_charging()`) and discharged over a time period. The charging works in the following way:

`1` is charging, current equation: `i = (vs/r)*np.exp((-1/(r*c))*t)`

`2` is discharging, current equation: `i = -(vs/r)*np.exp((-1/(r*c))*t)`

`0` is nothing happens

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

plt.style.use('ggplot')

#constants
c = 100 * 10**(-6) #farad
vs = 5 #volts
r = 2000 #ohms
#Max voltage
v_max = 4.8 #volts

def charge_current(t):
    i = (vs/r)*np.exp((-1/(r*c))*t) #current
    return i

def discharge_current(t):
    i = -(vs/r)*np.exp((-1/(r*c))*t) #current
    return i

def pv_charging():
    random_charge = random.randint(0,2)
    return random_charge

def pv_battery_charge(t):
    i = charge_current(t) #current
    vc = i * r #voltage
    p = i ** 2 #power
    return i, vc, p

def pv_battery_discharge(t):
    i = discharge_current(t)
    vc = i * r
    p = i ** 2
    return i, vc, p


if __name__ == '__main__':
    currents = []
    voltages = []
    power = []
    time = []
    charge_states = []

    for index, t in enumerate(range(0, 15, 1)): # t=[0,1,2,3...10]
        x = pv_charging() # 0
        isStarting = False

        if x == 1:
            i, vc, p = pv_battery_charge(t)
            power.append(p)
        elif x == 2:
            i, vc, p = pv_battery_discharge(t)
            power.append(p)
        else:
            if index != 0:
                i = currents[index-1]
                vc = voltages[index-1]
                p = power[index-1]
            else:
                i = 0
                vc = 0
                p = 0
            power.append(p)

        currents.append(i)
        voltages.append(vc)
        charge_states.append(x)
        time.append(t)

    print(time)
    print(charge_states)
    print(currents)
    plt.figure()

    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.plot(time,currents,'b-',linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel('Current (A)')
    plt.legend(['Current'],loc='best')

    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.plot(time,voltages,'k-',linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
    plt.legend(['Voltage'],loc='best')

    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.plot(time,power,'g-',linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel('Power (W)')
    plt.legend(['Power'],loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')

    plt.show()
```

Right now my plots look like this:
[image]

My lists that correlate to the output are:

Time (in seconds)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Charge States

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2]
```

Current

```
[0.0025, 0.0025, 1.1349982440621213e-07, 7.647558012545645e-10, 7.647558012545645e-10, 3.471985966241005e-14, 2.339405742210044e-16, -1.5762791900367474e-18, 1.0620885638228972e-20, 7.156296451373485e-23, 4.821874619909794e-25, -3.248953562518758e-27, -3.248953562518758e-27, -1.4750226353992652e-31, -9.938624339771617e-34]
```

I have it so that if `0` is randomly outputted in the charge states, the value is the previous value that was calculated, similar to a battery holding its charge. You can see in the lists that the plot is not coming out correctly. The battery should not be "discharging" until the 7th second. It can be seen in the output that the current values are so low that they are basically zero, so the power output and voltage output become zero.

**Problem**
I believe the issue is how I am using the charging equations to calculate the amount of charge in a battery at a certain time. I do not believe they are meant to be used the way I am using them. So what I am wondering is, what can I do to make the equations work in such a way that I can plot something similar to what I referenced above. Or if I should be using different equations.

If any clarification is needed on my question, just let me know.

Comment: It's probably not your main issue, but the power calculation seems completely off. It should be current times voltage so in your plot it should be something like 0.01 at the beginning and not a very small number.

Comment: I guess you forgot the resistance for the power calculation (I²R). For your general problem, shouldn't you just take the time difference between the points? Currently it seems like you calculate each time step as if that state would have started at t=0. Maybe for debugging I would at first not use a randomized state but a known sequence where you can easier think of what the expected output would be and see if that matches.